# Best way to track users correct timezone using moment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, momentjs

What is the best way to get the user's timezone? I'm using the MEAN stack and also have moment available to me. I would like to get the users timezone? I can do some regex but I would rather keep it simple and use either the Angular or moment framework?

The following params are no deprecated:

```
moment().format('zz')
moment().format('z')
```

Nice script available but due to late testing, not allowed to use it, https://github.com/entraigas/jstz

Thanks.

J

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks, from reading the post which linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript, I'm going to use new Date().toString().match(/([A-Z]+[\+-][0-9]+)/)[1] which will give me GMT+0100